# Converting meters to degrees for ST_DWithin

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am using a SRID with meters as the unit. This is my code:

```
ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull, cp."geoJson", 20)
```

I want to find out what the distance argument would be if my columns were of SRID 4326, i.e. how to convert 20 meters to degrees?

Please note I do not want to use

```
ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull::geography, cp."geoJson"::geography, 20)
```

as this casting is leading to very slow performance.

Can I use this as an appoximation: 1 degree = 111 km?

So 20 m can be 1/5550 = 1.801801801801802e-4 degrees

Comment: If your srid is in metres then work in metres throughout and all your problems will disappear

Comment: @IanTurton I tried this: ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull, cp."geoJson", 0.00017999), however the query has been running for an unreasonble amonth of time. P.S - the db admin is unwilling to change SRID to meters in the db for now, so am trying different hacks.

Comment: put all of your data in metres and use 20m - do not try to be clever with degree/metre conversions unless all your interactions are at the equator.

Comment: You seem to have posted a series of related questions around this same task of yours, each only targeting a snapshot of the actual intent of your query. To me this looks like a fundamental syntax, structure and data segmentation issue more than a question around a *specific* index, unit or statement order - several CTEs with multiple inlined sub-queries and dozens of filters, plenty of spatial operations and computational derivates...PGs planner is not almighty, and geometric calculations are costly.

Comment: You may be better off creating a (temporary, DDL based) ETL structure, extracting data in question into consecutively processed middle layers (tables, materialized views) with specific indexation and type conversions (e.g. `GEOMETRY` -> `GEOGRAPHY`) that you can control yourself - this may even help you identify the bottlenecks in your more compound queries in these questions of yours.

Comment: You absolutely **do not** want to use Cartesian approximation for distance in geodetic space. The answers will be sufficiently wrong as to be useless. @geozelot is right in that you have been thrashing on this one problem without support for too long. You need to get support from your management for a complete review of the task and what you need from the DBA staff. There are probably good reasons not to change the data used by others for your convenience, but that doesn't mean you can't engage with the DBA team to get what you need. You've only given us peeks into your task so we can't help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees - Wikipedia has a good overview of decimal degrees and distance.  The answer is - it depends on what you're using dwithin for.  I do, in fact, use degrees with st_dwithin in my work, but only to generally limit searches by distance, and only for a dataset that covers a small portion of the globe (biggest is statewide).  I would never use degrees to check if a geometry was X distance from another.  It will never be accurate.   Also, if you have a large area of coverage, you'll get large variations in distance per degree.

Comment: So many geospatial heavyweights giving advice on this one! Sure, I will insist on getting the DBA to store data in meters in the database.